# How to JOIN four tables together using one id

Tags: html, sql

I have four tables and I want to join them using SQL queries and display the product on product page

```
Table 1 [table name: A] has product_id and category_id, 
Table 2 [table name: B] has product_id, and our_price,  
Table 3 [table name: C] has product_id, and product_name  
Table 4 [table name: D] has product_id, description, and saving_price.
```

Here, I want to

`join Table A, B, C, and D` and `SELECT all product's` data `from tables B, C, D which category_id = 77 in table A`.

I want to print `product_name, description, saving_price, and our_price` on product page which have category id is 77.

Comment: Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Your request says exactly how to do it... what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably this is what you want, although hard to know from the way you have asked

```
SELECT
    A.product_id,
    A.category_id,
    B.our_price,
    C.product_name,
    D.description,
    D.saving_price
FROM
    A
    INNER JOIN B ON A.product_id = B.product_id
    INNER JOIN C ON A.product_id = C.product_id
    INNER JOIN D ON A.product_id = D.product_id
WHERE
    A.category_id = 77
```

The above assumes data exists in all tables. If you have missing data in some you may need to use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`

Comment: you should have read the comments in OP and analyzed the efforts by the OP, you shouldn't provide the answer to him, seriously he would be a beginner and this is going to do no good to him if he never tried it once, dont mind just saying